# CSS: divs are pushed down in the container

Tags: html, css, layout

I've put together this bit of html and css to display featured items for a homepage, but for some reason the contents of the box seem to make the boxes float to the bottom of the containing div and depending on the amount of text this means the boxes become miss-aligned.

I want the boxes to all remain the same height and all be aligned along the top of the blue div.

CSS:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

.icon_css { background: url(http://fauxbyte.esy.es/_codepen_resources/icon_css.png) #FFF; background-size: 80px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; }
.icon_php { background: url(http://fauxbyte.esy.es/_codepen_resources/icon_php7.png) #FFF; background-size: 75px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; }
.icon_jquery { background: url(http://fauxbyte.esy.es/_codepen_resources/icon_jquery.gif) #FFF; background-size: 110px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; }
.icon_bootstrap { background: url(http://fauxbyte.esy.es/_codepen_resources/icon_bootstrap.gif) #FFF; background-size: 160px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; }

body { margin: 0px; }

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.featuredItemWrap {
  background: #E7E7E7;
  width: 250px;
  height: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px; 
  margin-left: 5px; 
  margin-top: 25px;  
  text-align: center;
}

.featuredItemOuterWrap {
  background: #009CEF;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;

}

.featuredItemInner {
}

.featuredItemDesc {
  background: none;
  padding: 0px 20px 40px 20px;
  color: #444;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.featuredItemDesc h1 {
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
  font-size: 25px;
}

.featuredItemIcon {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #E7E7E7;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/MatthewBryce/pen/NrqExp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex layout for `.featuredItemOuterWrap` container and its' inner items:

```
.featuredItemOuterWrap{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aZOQqr)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solved it myself.

Simply used `vertical-align: top;` on my `.itemDivs`.